# Invoke a class function with a parameter in python

Tags: python, class

Let's say I have a simple linked list class:

```
class LL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.next = None
        self.previous = None

    def next(self):
        return self.next

    def previous(self):
        return self.previous
```

In this case, I want to invoke previous or next, based on what is passed into a function in another class, like so:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.node = LL()
    def move(direction):
        self.node = self.node.direction
```

S.t. when it makes a call, it would call `self.node.next()` or `self.node.previous()`.
Where move("next") would make a call to `self.node.next()`.
This doesn't work. Nor does

```
self.node = self.node.direction()
```

How would I go about accomplishing something like this?

I'm not sure how to even formally describe this- assigning a class attribute by calling an alternate class' method via a parameter?

Comment: well, how about `if direction == "next": node.next() elif direction == 'previous' ...` etc?

Comment: Why do your `next` and `previous` methods exist at all? They would provide no useful functionality even if they didn't get hidden by the `self.next = None` and `self.previous = None` assignments.

Comment: @user2357112 Ideally, this would make the program I'm building a little more extensible in the future. Right now, I'm using a Linked List w/ 4 directions, but this was a clear, simple example.
@juanpa.arrivillaga I'm trying to avoid a long list of `if` statements so that in the future I can add more modularity to how things are moving around.

Comment: @Whatamia you can use `getattr` as well. But how long is too long? How many of these attributes do you imagine having to support?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Fair criticism. It would seem that getattr would actually do what I want. Thanks. I'll also approve the other answer, as that also accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, it would be best to keep it simple with an `if` statement.

```
    def move(direction):
        if direction == 'next':
            self.node = self.node.next()
        elif direction == 'previous':
            self.node = self.node.previous()
        else:
            #handle the invalid input however you think is best
```

However, you should rename either the field or the method for both `next` and `previous`. I would recommend changing `next(self)` to `getNext(self)`. Alternately, you could change `self.next` to `self._next` to indicate that the field is not intended to be accessed directly.

Comment: Don't forget to invoke the methods with `()`.

Comment: @Idlehands in this case it will actually fail, since the instance attribute and the method names clash

Comment: @Idlehands Good catch. The methods are pointless as demonstrated, but it's how OP wants to do things apparently.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes I caught both of your comments as well.  I'm merely commenting on this answer's implementation.

Comment: I would suggest just not using a method and using direct attribute access, as that would be the pythonic way. Definitely *never* `getX`....

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm a Java programmer, professionally. I've never understood the Python communities aversion to that naming convention. Is there any particular reason why not `getX`?

Comment: Because you shouldn't be writing getters and setters in Python for simple attribute access and retrieval. So don't use `obj.getX`, just use `obj.x`. Don't use `obj.setX(val)`, use `obj.x = val`. If you later decide to control access to an attribute, you can use a `property`, and you can still use `obj.x` and `obj.x = val`. Properties are how Python does encapsulation. Read this: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php

Answer (score 0):

As @user2357112 demonstrated, your `LL` class itself has shadowing issues.  You'll probably want to modify it to perhaps one of the following:

```
class LL:
    def __init__(self):
        self._next = None
        self._previous = None

    # assign a different name
    def next(self):
        ... do something like move the node to next
        ... maybe change self._next on the way...
        return self._next

    # Or make use of property decorator    
    @property
    def previous(self):
        ... do something like move the node to previous
        return self._previous

    @previous.setter
    def previous(self, value):
        ... do something to change self._previous
```

Somehow I still don't think that's what you're after, but to answer the spirit of your question, you can use a `dict` like a switch statement in your `foo()` class like so:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.node = LL()
    def move(direction):
        _moves = {
            'next': self.node.next,
            'previous': self.node.previous,
            'nowhere': self.node.nowhere
        }

        # if you're invoking a method
        _moves.get(direction)()

        # if you're just referencing an attribute
        _moves.get(direction)
```

Conceptually I think it's more important to think about what you're trying to achieve with `LL` and `foo` before proceeding though.